# Redirect output from ffmeg to openssl

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, ffmpeg, openssl, aes

I'm using ubuntu and I'm trying to record a video using ffmpeg and encrypt it with AES using openssl.I want to begin the encryption and the record in parallel (bytes coming from ffmeg redirected to openssl to be encrypted and obtain at the end an encrypted video) but I have no idea how to do this, can pipelines help in this case ?

Comment: Writing a program can help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `pipe:` (or `-`) as your output for ffmpeg.  `openssl` will read the data from stdin if you don't specify any `-in` option.

So just

```
ffmpeg <whatever> pipe: | openssl enc <whatever>
```

Note that when specifying `pipe:` as the output, auto-detecting the output format is not possible, so it must be specified explicitly, e.g. `... -f matroska pipe:`. See `ffmpeg -formats` for a list of supported muxers, and refer to [FFmpeg Protocols Documentation: Pipe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe) for more info.

Comment: thanks for the answer but It's not working , I get an error : Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:' pipe:: Invalid argument

Comment: ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 5 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -t 5 -y output.mkv pipe: | openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in output.mkv -out result -k secret

Comment: Get rid of `output.mkv`.  You're not writing to a file, you are writing to a pipe!  Also, get rid of `-in output.mkv` in the openssl command.

Comment: Yes I tried also `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 5 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -t 5 -y  pipe: | openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt  -out result -k secret`   and still getting the same error.

Comment: Try getting rid of `-y`. Also try `pipe:1` instead of `pipe:` (though both work in the latest version).

Comment: Specify an output format.  Like `... -t 5 -f matroska pipe:1`